# Available VGG (or other convnet) weight checkpoints at different steps

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am interested in studying the errors of ConvNets at different steps of training, but I would like to avoid, if possible, to train the net myself. Do you know of any release of a CNN at different epochs? For instance, the ideal situation would be to have downloadable weights/checkpoints after 1, 2, 5, ... N epochs, ideally in either tf/keras or pytorch.

I know this question has already been asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403845/downloadable-weights-of-vgg-16-during-imagenet-training), but no useful answer was provided.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want this?!

Comment: Because I want to study the evolution of the errors at different timesteps of training. For instance, do CNN errors reflect some semantically meaningful distinction (e.g. animate vs inanimate) even at early stages of training?